# Apps Script getLastRow error (

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm creating an archiving function for a scheduling template.

I got it to work via the following code:

```
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range
function copySchedule2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheets()[3];
  var destination = ss.getSheets()[4];

  var range = source.getRange("A1:X64");  

  range.copyFormatToRange(destination, 1, 26, 1, 64);
  range.copyValuesToRange(destination, 1, 26, 1, 64);
}
```

However, since this is an on-going archiving, i'm trying to add each weeks schedule to the bottom of previous archive. I attempted this code:

```
function copySchedule() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheets()[3];
  var destination = ss.getSheets()[4]; 
  var range = source.getRange("A1:X64");  

  source.getRange("A:X").copyTo(destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow()+1));

}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
[15-10-26 17:24:28:093 EDT] Starting execution
[15-10-26 17:24:28:099 EDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[15-10-26 17:24:28:191 EDT] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0.092 seconds]
[15-10-26 17:24:28:193 EDT] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0.001 seconds]
[15-10-26 17:24:28:243 EDT] Sheet.getRange([A1:X64]) [0.049 seconds]
[15-10-26 17:24:28:302 EDT] Execution failed: Cannot convert function FindRows() { destinationRange = SpreadhseetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[4].getLastRow(); return destinationRange; } 1 to (class). (line 36, file "Copy v0.5") [0.146 seconds total runtime]
```

I'm new to JS so perhaps someone can point me in the right directions. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copyTo() needs a reference to a cell to know where it's supposed to paste the data.  You are just giving it the row number as getLastRow() returns a number.

Try appending a ,1 to tell it to start pasting in column A:

```
source.getRange("A:X").copyTo(destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow()+1, 1));
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Quick question - are there some better resources then google documentation? I find their examples a bit lacking.

Comment: While nowhere near exhausting I find the reference to be fairly good personally. I feel that if you understand JS and grasp the concept of Spreadsheets, sheets, ranges and their properties everything falls into place. Unofrtunately there are not a lot of resources out there, two books and a [donation based one](https://leanpub.com/googlespreadsheetprogramming) that I personally find very lacking and little more than an enriched copypaste from the basic google tutorials.